# Python: how to read a config file with only keys (no values)

Tags: python, parsing, configuration-files

I would like to use the following `.ini` file with [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html).

```
[Site1]
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.2.0/24

[Site2]
192.168.3.0/24
192.168.4.0/24
```

Unfortunately a call to `read()` dumps the following error:

```
import ConfigParser
c = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
c.read("test.ini")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 546, in _read
    raise e
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: test.ini
        [line  2]: '192.168.1.0/24\n'
        [line  3]: '192.168.2.0/24\n'
        [line  6]: '192.168.3.0/24\n'
        [line  7]: '192.168.4.0/24\n'
```

My understanding is that the expected format is `key = value` (a `value` is required).

My questions:

- is `ConfigParser` usable for such files?
- if not: is there a good alternative to parse similar files?

I can reformat the config file but would like to keep a simple, raw list of entries per section -- as opposed to faking the `key = value` format with something like `range1 = 192.168.1.0/24`

Comment: ConfigParser has some options while creating object of it. I don't remember now. Search it

Comment: @Farhadix: I read the docs mentioned in my post. They do not explicitly mention the possibility to use value-less entries. However i) I found out that there are sometimes hidden or less obvious ways to do things in Python :) and ii) I hope that there is a good alternative to plain .ini files which would fit with my format.

Comment: Commenting to my comment: it turns out that I obviously need to improve my reading as the docs do say that one can use value-less entries :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `allow_no_value` parameter:

```
import ConfigParser
c = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
c.read("test.ini")
```

According to [`ConfigParser.RawConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser) (base class of ConfigParser):

> When `allow_no_value` is true (default: **False**), options without values
>   are accepted; the value presented for these is **None**.

**NOTE**: available in Python 2.7+, 3.2+

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I do not know how I missed that in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `allow_no_value` parameter to `True`

```
import ConfigParser
c = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
c.read("test.ini")
```

Also check out [ConfigObj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html) as an alternative.

Comment: Please do not duplicate the answer.

Comment: @falsetru: sorry, your answer was not there when I started writing. It happens quite often with me. its probably a meta question but what should I do when such things happen?

Comment: I delete my answer, if my answer does not provide any additional information and my answer was posted after the other's.

Comment: I would have deleted it. but now it has 2 down votes. why is that? is it a wrong answer? When I wrote down my answer and hit post, according to all the information I had, the question was unanswered.

Comment: @lalli ConfigObj does not allow options without a value like ConfigParser does via `allow_no_value=True`.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Now it has vote zero, please delete that.